# Правильная организация работы с базой данных и внешними API в Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, best-practice

Здравствуйте.

Не так давно начал учить Laravel 5.3. До этого пользовался простеньким фреймворком CodeIgniter 3, где с организацией кода, в принципе, все понятно: плодишь себе тучу моделей на все случаи жизни и всё. В Laravel же есть всякие сервис-провайдеры, сервис-контейнеры, фасады, контракты, миддлвейры... и во всём этом по одним лишь докам довольно сложно разобраться. Начинаешь читать про сервис-контейнеры, а там внезапно начинают ссылаться на сервис-провайдеры. Решаешь и про них почитать, а там внезапно ссылаются на что-то ещё. Таким образом замыкается Колесо Сансары и появляется желание пойти поваляться на диване.

Смотрите. Вот у меня есть регистрация, после которой пользователю на почту отправляется письмо со ссылкой, перейдя по которой он должен активировать аккаунт. Заставить это работать несложно; вопрос лишь в том, насколько это эстетично получится.

Я читал, что в контроллерах обращаться к БД - дурной тон, и вообще *keep your controllers thin and models fat*. Но как в таком случае обработать примерно такую ситуацию, где я создаю новый аккаунт и затем отправляю письмо для активации аккаунта? Как и куда это вынести из контроллера?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

/* Eloquent */
use App\User;

/* Requests */
use App\Http\Requests\Register;

/* Mailables */
use App\Mail\ConfirmRegistration;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function store(Register $request)
    {
        $created_user = User::create([
            'name'     => $request->input('name'),
            'email'    => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
        ]);

        Mail::to($request->input('email'))->send(new ConfirmRegistration($created_user));

        return $created_user;
    }
}
```

Второй вопрос из той же песни об организации кода. У меня есть классы, работающие с API различных сайтов (VK, Imgur и т.п.). В каждом таком классе есть примерно одинаковый набор методов (`auth()`, `refreshToken()`, `api()` и т.п.). Просто обычные классы, лежащие в директории `Classes` внутри директории `app`. Можно ли их оттуда вынести и преобразовать во что-нибудь, что из коробки поддерживается фреймворком (типа сервис-провайдера)? Ждет ли котёл с кипящим маслом тех, кто будет вызывать методы подобных классов внутри контроллера? Или как из вопроса выше их надо куда-то вынести?

Спасибо всем, кто хотя бы прочитает эту простыню текста, и особенное спасибо всем, кто ответит.

Answer (score 1):

В программировании есть **определенные принципы**, которые легко решают два ваших вопроса. Начнем.

1. А почему собственно плохо? Код написан понятно, с минимальной вероятностью будет использоваться в другом контроллере или месте, не превышает допустимых норм размера, смысла его выносить нет. 
   Конечно, можно создать класс, который назывался бы UserManager, содержащий в себе методы создания пользователя, создания соответствующих сущностей к нему (кошельки и т.д), и вынести это все в отдельный модуль, который бы пригодился бы в панели администратора, когда нужно будет создать пользователя. В вашем случае вы создаете запись, отправляете письмо, есть ли смысл выносить это? Мое мнение, на данном этапе - нет, не стоит, если не планируете еще создавать 100 сущностей, выполнять какие-то дополнительные действия, когда код контроллера может превратиться в божественный метод (тысячи строк). Прочитайте про принцип **KISS** — **keep it simple stupid (делайте вещи проще).**
2. Общие методы всегда должны быть в одном классе и остальные классы должны реализовывать или наследовать соответствующие методы, не требуется десяток раз писать один и тот же метод. Предположим, вы можете определить интерфейс **ClientApi** и определить методы **auth()**, **refreshToken()**, реализовывать его во всех классах, которые определяют работу со сторонним API. **(см. принципы SOLID)**. Я абсолютно не вижу смысла выносить его куда-либо или преобразовывать, кроме как отложенно в **сервис-контейнер**, чтобы автоматический подключить конфигурацию к этому API (логины, пароли) из соответствующих файлов, чтобы его можно было подгрузить одной командой в нужном месте.

Answer (score 1):

Сервис-контейнеры, как раз и нужны для того, что выносить работу с моделями в "отдельное место". Исходя из документации (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#introduction), мы можем увидеть в примере некий класс "**UserRepository**" - это и есть сервис-контейнер. Не важно как его называть(**UserRepository**, **UserContainer**, **Users** и т.д.), главной его задачей является работа с конкретной моделью.

То есть обращаться к модели вам нужно ТОЛЬКО из этого контейнера. Конечно никто не запрещает искать модель из контроллера, но это (по моему мнению) пример плохого тона. Я, например, поставил для себя правило, что даже к таким методам как **find()**, **findOrFail()**, я буду обращаться из контейнера. Это поможет мне в том случае, если вдруг (каким-то чудесным образом) в ядре Laravel переименуют эти методы, то мне не придется искать по всему проекту, где я вызываю тот или иной метод. Я смогу все поправить в контейнерах.

Из примера документации, можно увидеть, что контейнер UserRepository создается в конструкторе контроллера. Так необходимо делать, если в дальнейшем будете тестировать свой контроллер. Это даст возможность подменить контейнер Mock-объектом и лишний раз не обращаться к БД. Опять же, никто не запрещает создавать его прямо в action =)

Сервис-контейнер (если не использовать конструктор), можно вызвать еще одним способом:

```
app(UserRepository::class)->{метод_который_нужно_вызвать}(/* $params */);
```

Если из вашего примера вынести строчки создания пользователя, поместить их в контейнер, то будет примерно так:

```
//service container
class UserRepository {
    public function create(Register $request){
        return User::create([
            'name'     => $request->input('name'),
            'email'    => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        ]);
    }
}

// controller action
public function store(Register $request)
{
    $created_user = app(UserRepository::class)->create($request);

    Mail::to($request->input('email'))->send(new ConfirmRegistration($created_user));

    return $created_user;
}
```

Отпраку писем можно организовать там же, а можно из action через очереди (queue).

P.S. Actions в контроллере должны быть public